# Return missing number in array of integers 1 - 9

Tags: javascript

I ran the code using different arrays missing a number between 1 - 9, but it kept returning -1.

```js
function findMissing(arrOfNumbers) {
  const integers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  for (let index = 0; index < arrOfNumbers.length; index++) {
    if (integers[index] !== arrOfNumbers[index]) {
      return integers[index];
    }
    return -1;
  }
}

console.log(findMissing([0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9])); //returns -1 instead of 5
```

Comment: You're returning -1 inside the loop

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Your problem statement is unclear, but your code says if the integer at integers[index] does not match the integer at arrOfNumbers[index], the function shall return -1.  The loop will not execute under those conditions.

Comment: Move `return -1` outside the `for` loop.

Comment: I'd not expect 5 but 2 as result ...

Comment: if you had indented with the Whitesmiths style rather than the kernighan & Ritchie, you would have immediately seen that your `return -1` is misplaced

Comment: You're looping through the arrOfNumbers and not your integer's check array.
Therefore, every number in arrOfNumbers is IN your integer check array. Switching this fixes the issue. In addition your return -1 statement is inside the for loop. move it out and it should return the match. 

In this case though, the return value will be 2, because the number 2 is missing (not 5).

Comment: @ArkyAsmal If you look closely, you will see, that it doesn't matter which array you are iterating through. Because the return value of that function (if the `return -1` is placed correctly after the loop) is the first value in the `integers` array which is different from the respective index in the `allOfNumbers` array. Even if the latter was empty, this will return the correct result (again given that `return -1` is placed correctly)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the problem, you want missing elements from array 2. if so, simply use,

```
arr1.filter(x=> !arr2.includes(x));
```

In your case

```js
const array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const array2 = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const result = array1.filter(x=> !array2.includes(x)); // returns 2 , 5

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can spread the array over an object and compare the key and value pairs of the object. If key and value are different then that means some value is missing in the input array that is out of range. Note the use of `!=`, it is intentional to compare values and not types.

```js
function findMissing(arrOfNumbers) {
  const obj = {...arrOfNumbers};
  for(const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if(key != val) {
      return key;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

// returns 2 since it is the first missing value in the order
console.log(findMissing([0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

Comment: Code-Only answers are discouraged. Please describe briefly what you did to fix that error ...